# Trying to display a radio button on my table, but even with some css, no luck

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, radio-button

I added a radio button element to my table.  However, it doesn't appear on my page.  I took the same exact code and created a snippet and the radio button does appear. Also, I added a background color, just to see where it would be located and it turns out the radio button is covering my text.   Does anyone know why this is happening and how to fix it?

EDIT: This is also made under Bootstrap 4.

This how it looked when I added a background color to the radio button.
[image]

```html
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-25">
                <h1>ABC Corp</h1>
                <h4>Bill for the month of: June</h4>
                <h4>Payment due: 5/10/2020</h4>
                <hr />
                <table id="billing">
                 
                        <tr>
                            <th width="25%">Company</th>
                            <th width="25%">Plan</th>
                            <th width="25%">Packages</th>
                            <th width="25%">Price/pkg</th>
                            <th>Total</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>ACME</td>
                            <td>Premium</td>
                            <td>10,000</td>
                            <td>$0.039</td>
                            <td>
                                <div>
                                    <label><input type="radio" id='regular' name="optradio">390.00</label>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>NB Distribution</td>
                            <td>Professional</td>
                            <td>1,000</td>
                            <td>$0.049</td>
                            <td>
                                <div>
                                    <label><input type="radio" id='regular' name="optradio">49.00</label>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
              
                </table>
                <hr>
                <p>Balance due <span class="price" style="color:black"><b>$439.00</b></span></p>
               <hr >
        </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: First of all the radio buttons are shown in browser @csb00 and also you have to make different id's for two radio buttons.

Answer (score 0):

don't enclose your input within the label tag, instead separate those two like below.

```
    <input type="radio" id='regular' name="optradio">
    <label for="regular">390.00</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `display: flex` on the label:

```css
label {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-25">
    <h1>ABC Corp</h1>
    <h4>Bill for the month of: June</h4>
    <h4>Payment due: 5/10/2020</h4>
    <hr />
    <table id="billing">

      <tr>
        <th width="25%">Company</th>
        <th width="25%">Plan</th>
        <th width="25%">Packages</th>
        <th width="25%">Price/pkg</th>
        <th>Total</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>ACME</td>
        <td>Premium</td>
        <td>10,000</td>
        <td>$0.039</td>
        <td>
          <div>
            <label><input type="radio" id='regular' name="optradio">390.00</label>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>NB Distribution</td>
        <td>Professional</td>
        <td>1,000</td>
        <td>$0.049</td>
        <td>
          <div>
            <label><input type="radio" id='regular' name="optradio">49.00</label>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>

    </table>
    <hr>
    <p>Balance due <span class="price" style="color:black"><b>$439.00</b></span></p>
    <hr>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all the radio buttons are shown in browser @csb00 and also you have to make different id's for two radio buttons.

[image]